# Spring 3 with Hibernate 6.2+ Application startup fail - mappingModelPart is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-6.x

I have a Java Spring Boot app (Spring boot 3.1.0) for which I am trying to update hibernate for. The reason for the upgrade being that with the older versions I have encountered application braking bugs and wanted to see if the newer versions fix that.
Any version starting from 6.2.0 seems to crash the app at startup with the following error:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
 resource
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
 [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory;
 nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
 "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getNavigableRole()"
 because "mappingModelPart" is null     at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931)
    at
 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at
 org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733)
    at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435)
    at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305)
    at
 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294)
    at com.frim.backend.application.Application.main(Application.java:23)
 Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
 default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
 "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getNavigableRole()"
 because "mappingModelPart" is null     at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
    at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816)
    at
 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
    ... 16 common frames omitted Caused by:
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
 "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getNavigableRole()"
 because "mappingModelPart" is null     at
 org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.lambda$registerEmbeddableMappingType$1(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:229)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)   at
 org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.visitRegisteredComponents(MetadataImpl.java:573)
    at
 org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.registerEmbeddableMappingType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:225)
    at
 org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:210)
    at
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:320)
    at
 org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init(SessionFactoryImpl.java:270)
    at
 org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431)
    at
 org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1455)
    at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
    at
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
 
 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Prior to this update there was no issue. Is there something new with these versions that could cause this, maybe a new property or extra requirements?

Comment: Well it is a new version so there is obviously something new. Depending on which Spring Boot version (your title mentions Spring which isn't the same as Spring Boot!) it might or might not be compatible. I also wonder **how** you upgraded the version of hibernate (and why upgrade to a new version then the supported 6.1 line). Additionally please edit your question to use a code block around your stacktrace instead of a quote (as that makes it unreadable and unformatted).

Comment: I upgraded the version of hibernate by adding it to the pom with a newer version. The reason for the upgrade being that with the older versions I have encountered application braking bugs and wanted to see if the newer versions fix that.

Comment: If you want to upgrade hibernate add `hibernate.version` as a property to your maven pom, don't go to override individual dependencies. However depending on your database in use and which Spring (Boot) version in use this might not work (as classes got removed and replaced in Hibernate 6.2 for which the framework needed to change).

Comment: The Spring boot version is use is 3.1.0 which is compatible with hibernate 6.2.+  version, as per the maven repository. Regarding the database in use, it is a HANA database.

Comment: Spring Boot 3.1 is (partially) compatible as there are removed classes in Hibernate 6.2 which are still being referenced in the main framework. There have been a few questions on that (and has been fixed in an upcoming release of Spring). Nonetheless as stated you should override the version using the method as described instead of adding individual dependencies.

Comment: Anyway please add your pom, some configuration etc. as currently there is too little information.

Answer (score 19):

A few days ago we stumbled upon the same error while migrating an application from Spring Boot 2.7.0 with Spring Data JPA (Hibernate Core 5.6.9-Final) to Spring Boot 3.1.0 (Hibernate Core 6.2.2-Final) as you can see here:

```
2023-06-12T09:39:17.993+03:00 ERROR 23852 --- [    Test worker] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because "mappingModelPart" is null
2023-06-12T09:39:17.994+03:00  WARN 23852 --- [    Test worker] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because "mappingModelPart" is null
2023-06-12T09:39:17.994+03:00  INFO 23852 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-06-12T09:39:17.996+03:00  INFO 23852 --- [    Test worker] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-06-12T09:39:18.012+03:00  INFO 23852 --- [    Test worker] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-12T09:39:18.044+03:00 ERROR 23852 --- [    Test worker] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because "mappingModelPart" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    -- some lines were truncated
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because "mappingModelPart" is null
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
    ... 100 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because "mappingModelPart" is null
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.lambda$registerEmbeddableMappingType$1(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:229)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.visitRegisteredComponents(MetadataImpl.java:570)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.registerEmbeddableMappingType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 104 common frames omitted

2023-06-12T09:39:18.062+03:00 ERROR 23852 --- [    Test worker] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener] to prepare test instance [com.manios.product.discount.DiscountServiceTest@531a82]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@5ffce9b4 testClass = com.manios.product.discount.DiscountServiceTest, locations = [], classes = [com.manios.product.discount.DiscountServiceApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["spring.profiles.active:test", "org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@b86cb18, [ImportsContextCustomizer@6f0408a9 key = [com.manios.embedded.qpid.config.EmbeddedQpidAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@3386ed8, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@4571cebe, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@99c78cde, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@62d42eb7, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@fae96cc0], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$before$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:203)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because "mappingModelPart" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1405)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:118)
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because "mappingModelPart" is null
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
    ... 100 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EmbeddableValuedModelPart.getNavigableRole()" because "mappingModelPart" is null
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.lambda$registerEmbeddableMappingType$1(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:229)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.visitRegisteredComponents(MetadataImpl.java:570)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.registerEmbeddableMappingType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.finishInitialization(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.initializeMappingModel(SessionFactoryImpl.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 104 common frames omitted
```

It seems that in our case the error was hidden in the fact that one `DiscountEntity` class was declaring more `@Id` fields than the ones declared in its  private key `DiscountEntityPK` class. Therefore as you can see in `DiscountEntityPK.java`, although the composite private key consists of 2 columns:

```java
package com.manios.product.discount;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

public class DiscountEntityPK implements Serializable {
    private String companyId;
    private long discountId;

    @Column(name = "company_id", nullable = false, length = 2)
    @Id
    public String getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(String companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    @Column(name = "discount_id", nullable = false)
    @Id
    public long getDiscountId() {
        return discountId;
    }

    public void setDiscountId(long discountId) {
        this.discountId = discountId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        DiscountEntityPK that = (DiscountEntityPK) o;
        return discountId == that.discountId &&
                Objects.equals(companyId, that.companyId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(companyId, discountId);
    }
}
```

the actual entity class, `DiscountEntity.java`, had 2 more fields annotated with the `@Id` annotation (search in the code for `INCORRECT ANNOTATION`)

```java
package com.manios.product.discount;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Objects;
import jakarta.persistence.Basic;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.IdClass;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "discount")
@IdClass(DiscountEntityPK.class)
public class DiscountEntity {
  private String companyId;
  private long discountId;
  private String discountType;
  private Date fromDate;
  private Date toDate;
  private String discountText;
  private long priority;
  private long discountLevel;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "company_id", nullable = false, length = 2)
  public String getCompanyId() {
    return companyId;
  }

  public void setCompanyId(String companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
  }

  @Id
  @Column(name = "discount_id", nullable = false)
  public long getDiscountId() {
    return discountId;
  }

  public void setDiscountId(long discountId) {
    this.discountId = discountId;
  }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "discount_type", nullable = false, length = 2)
  public String getDiscountType() {
    return discountType;
  }

  public void setDiscountType(String discountType) {
    this.discountType = discountType;
  }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "from_date", nullable = false)
  public Date getFromDate() {
    return fromDate;
  }

  public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
  }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "to_date", nullable = false)
  public Date getToDate() {
    return toDate;
  }

  public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
    this.toDate = toDate;
  }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "disc_text", nullable = false, length = 240)
  public String getDiscountText() {
    return discountText;
  }

  public void setDiscountText(String discountText) {
    this.discountText = discountText;
  }

  //     ------------------------
  @Id // <-- INCORRECT ANNOTATION. This should be @Basic instead
  @Column(name = "priority", nullable = false)
  public long getPriority() {
    return priority;
  }

  public void setPriority(long priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
  }

  //     ------------------------
  @Id // <-- INCORRECT ANNOTATION. This should be @Basic instead
  @Column(name = "discount_level", nullable = false)
  public long getDiscountLevel() {
    return discountLevel;
  }

  public void setDiscountLevel(long discountLevel) {
    this.discountLevel = discountLevel;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    DiscountEntity that = (DiscountEntity) o;
    return discountId == that.discountId &&
            Objects.equals(companyId, that.companyId) &&
            Objects.equals(discountType, that.discountType) &&
            Objects.equals(fromDate, that.fromDate) &&
            Objects.equals(toDate, that.toDate) &&
            Objects.equals(priority, that.priority) &&
            Objects.equals(discountLevel, that.discountLevel);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {

    return Objects
            .hash(companyId, discountId, discountType, fromDate, toDate, priority, discountLevel);
  }
}
```

In order to find out we had to explicitly debug and add breakpoints in the `MappingMetamodelImpl` class. After replacing the `@Id` annotation with `@Basic` annotation in columns `"discount_level"` and `"priority"` the problem was fixed. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Christos, discovered I had the same issue. You saved me hours of debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much! I faced the same problem and your solution saved hours!!

Comment: Christos you are my hero today! This post most likely saved me hours of trouble.

Comment: The more recent versions of Hibernate are unforgiving of some mistakes that were allowed in version 4. After upgrading my project to Spring Boot 3 I had to debug the project and set a breakpoint on `org.hibernate.MappingException` to find the offending field. Unfortunately Hibernate doesn't print a helpful message and I had to manually check all @IdClass annotated classes to find the culprit.

Comment: Save my day in debugging too !!! Thanks man !