# Spring Boot 3.1 Upgrade: ERROR: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.size()" because "genericTypes" is null

Tags: spring-boot, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink

I'm trying to upgrade my spring boot project from 3.0 to 3.1, but I'm getting this error during Maven install Eclipselink weave step: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.size()" because "genericTypes" is null

I don't really know where to start with this, there's no hint at what could be causing it.

Could it be that somewhere in one of my @Entity classes I've made a mistake with the annotations?

I tried fixing up my entity mapping annotations as per this post: [Spring 3 with Hibernate 6.2+ Application startup fail - mappingModelPart is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76412629/spring-3-with-hibernate-6-2-application-startup-fail-mappingmodelpart-is-null)

But that didn't do anything and I can't find any other posts about this issue.

I'm also using eclipselink-maven-plugin during the point it's failing, and I tried upgrading the dependencies within this plugin because I noticed the org.springframework versions were at version 6.0.7 and I'm using 6.0.12 in my project (using this version because it's supposed to work with Spring Boot 3.1).

Comment: Maybe show the entity and the full exception stack - you could try removing entities from your project to narrow it down to one. Is this a step for static weaving during build?

Comment: Yeah so I actually did this after posting and was able to narrow the issue down to my plugin com.ethlo.persistence.tools:eclipselink-maven-plugin which actually does the static weaving. I created an issue on the github repo and the owner said that there are usages with SB 3.1.x. He said my local environment probably didn't refresh after upgrading dependencies, but I haven't had any luck troubleshooting that yet